# passing argument to method that updates store in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want a user be able to input text into an input box and based on this would like to search an api. I am using `redux` and `redux-thunk`. I am unsure how I should pass the text that is inputted as an argument to the API call.

If I wasn't using redux and thunk, I would set the state of the component as

```
this.state = {
    movie: ''
}
```

and then on the `input type=text` I would update the `movie` value `onChange` with `e.target.value`. What is the approach that should be taken when using react with redux?

My code looks like as follows.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';

function reducer(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_MOVIE':
      return action.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);


class App extends Component {

    getMovie(){
        this.props.getMovie();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='text'>
                <input type='submit' onClick={this.props.getMovie}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function getMovie(movie){
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + movie)
        .then(function(data){
            dispatch(resolvedGetMovie(data.data));
        })
    }
}

function resolvedGetMovie(data){
    return {
        type: '
          GET_MOVIE ',
        data: data
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        movie: state
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getMovie : () => dispatch(getMovie())
    }
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedApp />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When getting started with `redux` it's easy to get carried away and place all application state within reducers. But, for form fields, UI related state, and other state only relevant to a specific component, it can be beneficial to store this within the state of the `component`. For the example you provided, you should keep track of the `input` value in the state of the component and then pass that value to your action (`getMovie`)

For example:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            movie: ''
        }        
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            movie: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        const {movie} = this.state;
        this.props.getMovie(movie);
    }

    render() {
        const {movie} = this.state;

        return(
            <div>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={movie}
                />
                <input type='submit' onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```